# Decrypting WPA with wireshark

Tags: wireshark, wpa, decryption

Hi I want to decrypt my WPA packets which i gathered by sniffing with airodump-ng.

The problem is that even after I have the 4-way handshake packets (they are correct) i don't know how to extract the PSK so i can put it in the IEEE 802.11 wireshark preferences. However i created the "raw" PSK but after i typed it into WPA decrytpion keys and enabled the decryption it still doesnt want to work. Wireshark is doing the decrytpion but it doesn't changes anything i still see only 802.11 protocol packets (I have about 20k of them).

- WPA-PSK:ee2b63f6068bdb1b7935ca7a5c5e3a5303c56f2ab3a60e8f130fbea1e305010d "raw" psk
- password:london84
- essid: virginmedia81**

Answer (score -1):

I get a different PSK for that passphrase and SSID:
`2b0c32fad932d2e8dc6f6209937ae5ccd89866bde2611b83c3fb73bd79bd32e3`

Comment: ... I hid my network name from you. it has 2 stars (*) you see ? Anyways is there something wrong if i have correct PSK ?